# How to rename a column in a SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, select, rename

If I do `SELECT name, ISNULL(license, 0) FROM table;` I get a resulting table with the license column having no name ("Column1" on my xml), how do I give it a name in the query so it makes my life easier when manipulating it on my application? I tried finding it but could only find how to rename the column on the table itself, instead of renaming the column on the table generated by the `SELECT`.

To simplify: `ISNULL` removes the name of the column in the generated by my `SELECT` and I want to bring it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an alias:

```
SELECT name, ISNULL(license, 0) AS license FROM table;
```

Comment: Or `ISNULL(license, 0) license` or `license = ISNULL(license, 0)`